# jQuery function returns undefined ? why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, undefined

http://www.kupe.nl/badkamer3.html

I can't get allong with this online code thingy, just wont make a code block .. )

the jQuery function loadingAjax() is undefined ? this action is called when all the radios are filled in. some part of this form is retreived using an another function.

If you want to take a test

select the "New York" model. and proceed filling the form.. and submitting the button

Please help,

Thanks

js code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ptmodel label").click(function() {

    var mainImage = $(this).attr("name");
    var targetRadio = $(this).attr("for");
        $("#main_image img").attr({ src: 'http://www.kupe.nl/media/privatetime/images/smaller/' + mainImage + '.jpg' });
    $("#" +targetRadio).attr("checked", "checked");


    var selected = mainImage;
    var selecteddataString = 'in_pt_model_label='+ selected;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "badkamer_sets.php",
    data: selecteddataString,
    success: function(selected){
    $("#ptsize_check").html(selected);
        }

    });     
});

function loadingAjax(my_div){
        var size = $('input:radio[name=in_pt_artikel]:checked').val();
        var color = $('input:radio[name=in_pt_color]:checked').val();
        var model = $('input:radio[name=in_pt_model]:checked').val();

           if(model == '' || model == null){
        $('#ptmodel_check').html('<font color="red">Selecteer een Model a.u.b</font>');

        }
        if (size == '' || size == null){
         $('#ptsize_check').html('<font color="red">Selecteer een Opstelling a.u.b</font>');

        }
        if (color == '' || color == null){
         $('#ptcolor_check').html('<font color="red">Selecteer een Front a.u.b</font>');

        }
        else {

        var dataString = 'in_pt_model='+ model + '&in_pt_color=' + color + '&in_pt_artikel=' + size;
    //$("#"+div_id).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"> saving...');

        $('#pt_form').hide();
        $('#'+my_div).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"> Een moment geduld alstublieft...');


        $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "badkamer_submit.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(msg){
            window.location="http://www.box7shop.nl/" + msg +".html";
    }
});

    }
}
});


</script>
```

( thnx everone for the responses )

I got my problem solved like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#ptmodel label").click(function() {


    var mainImage = $(this).attr("name");
    var targetRadio = $(this).attr("for");
        $("#main_image img").attr({ src: 'http://www.kupe.nl/media/privatetime    /images/smaller/' + mainImage + '.jpg' });
    $("#" +targetRadio).attr("checked", "checked");

    var selected = mainImage;
    var selecteddataString = 'in_pt_model_label='+ selected;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "badkamer_sets.php",
    data: selecteddataString,
    success: function(selected){
    $("#ptsize_check").html(selected)
    }

    });     
});

$("#submitimg").live("click", function() {

var size =  $('input:radio[name=in_pt_artikel]:checked').val();
var color = $('input:radio[name=in_pt_color]:checked').val();
var model = $('input:radio[name=in_pt_model]:checked').val();

if(model === '' || model === null){
        $('#ptmodel_check').html('<font color="red">Selecteer een Model a.u.b</font>');
    return false;
        }
        if (size === '' || size === null){
         $('#ptsize_check').html('<font color="red">Selecteer een Opstelling     a.u.b</font>');
    return false;
        }
        if (color === '' || color === null){
         $('#ptcolor_check').html('<font color="red">Selecteer een Front     a.u.b</font>');
        return false;
        }
        else {

        var dataString = 'in_pt_model='+ model + '&in_pt_color=' + color + '&in_pt_artikel=' + size;
    //$("#"+div_id).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"> saving...');

    $('#pt_form').hide();
    $('#myDiv').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"> Een moment geduld     alstublieft...');

        $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "badkamer_submit.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(msg){
            window.location='http://www.box7shop.nl/' + msg + '.html';

    }
    });
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Please post any relevant code in the question rather than directing to external site.

Comment: Works for me in Firefox. What browser are you using?

Comment: +1 for operational in chrome. Are you using Netscape Navigator? But seriously - it sounds like you're using IE which is much less tolerant to silly mistakes like extra commas. If you have too many commas, chrome and firefox usually ignore them where IE will crash.

Comment: I'm using Firefox / Chrome / IE .. It's not working in all of them .. It should hide all div's and show up a waiting GIF while waiting for the response.. after response it should do a window.location --- > indeed +1 for chrome

Comment: YAY! see post ! thnx everyone !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to remove the last "});" before the end script tag in the head of the document.

Change:

```
    }
});
```

To:

```
    }
```

Comment: I may have looked too quickly, but it appeared as though you started with declaring the function inside the "$(document).ready()" and then moved it outside but kept the closing "});"

Answer (score 0):

I used to have some trouble with IE when i tried to get attributes with $.attr() that are not valid html. I have never used the attribute "for" and dont know if there is any attribute like that, but if it is invalid that may be the cause.

Try to change it to rel="" instead.

Comment: for matches the form field. It returns OK .. there is nothing wrong with the first part of the script. I guess.. :P - I'll give it a try

Comment: Nm, i figured it was for the label and not for the input, and it is valid. sry.